# How to add a image inside var quotes

Tags: var

```
<body>
  <div id="quote"></div>
<div id="image"></div>
  <script>
    (function() {
      var quotes = [
        {
          text: "test1",
            }]
$('image').html("<img src='https://image.com/image.png'>")
        },
 {
          text: "test2",

        }
      ];
      var quote = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)];
      document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML =
        '<span>' + quote.text + '</span>';
    })();
  </script>
</body>
```

Updated

This is my code and i want to add an image here. I tried adding $('image').html("https://image.com/image.png'>") but it didn't work

Comment: Please share the technology

Answer (score 0):

You can add link to image or byteArray:

```
<script>
(function() {
  var quotes = [
    {
      text: "Sample text",
      byte: fileInputInByteArray,
      imageSrc: "http://images/example.jpg"
    } 
</script>
```